# Where can I find Nectar Tea?

Tags: atelier-annie-alchemists-of-si

One of the rank 3 resort jobs at the Hotel requires **Nectar Tea**.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Nectar Tea in the game. This is a typo for the item **Nectar Dew**.

You can learn the Nectar Dew recipe from the **Mystery Gem** book sold in the Library beginning October of year 2.